# Send a http 401 error code instead of default login page, spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using a basic authorization with the Spring Security. I configure the latter via Java config.

I would like to send to a client the HTTP 401 error code with the message "Invalid login and password" if they are invalid. However, currently Spring Security simply displays me a default pop-up window.

Here is my Spring security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/pages/index.html");

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AjaxAuthorizationPoint());
}
```

As far as I understood, I have to add the custom `authentificationEntryPoint` to handle the case of the invalid credentials i.e. I have to send there a 401 error code with the error message

Here is the code for it. For the sake of simplicity, the body of the method is rather simple.

```
public class AjaxAuthorizationPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint{

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request,
                         final HttpServletResponse response,
                         final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("blah");

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

However, the method `public void commence()` doesn't fire up, when I enter an invalid login and password and Spring simply sends me the default login pop-up window.

How can I redefine the default strategy? How can I configure the Spring security to send a HTTP 401 error code instead of displaying a default login page?

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have found a solution for my problem. Here the code that does exactly what I need.

Spring security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new AjaxAuthorizationPoint("/ajax_login"));

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/pages/index.html");
}
```

And custom ajax authorization point:

```
public class AjaxAuthorizationPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    public AjaxAuthorizationPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.setStatus(403);
        response.getWriter().print("Invalid login/password");
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any code review.

Comment: response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);